# How to test actions from redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, redux-thunk

How do I check if redux action is working ? and at the end of the execution, check dataState for data ?

For example:

To test the function of the authorization in the application. expect(AuthMethod(login, password));

Action:

```
return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(AuthLoading());

    try {
      var date = new Date().getDate();
      var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1; 
      var year = new Date().getFullYear();
      var hours = new Date().getHours(); 
      var min = new Date().getMinutes(); 
      var sec = new Date().getSeconds();
      var time =
        date + '-' + month + '-' + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + min + ':' + sec;

      let response = await fetch(
        'http://' + ServerLink + ':' + ServerPort + '/tmo/rest/user',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            login: login,
            password: password,
            deviceSerialNumber: '1111111', 
            currentAppVersion: AppVersion,
            currentDateTime: time,
          }),
        },
      );

      let data = await response.json();
      if (data.sessionToken === '') {
        dispatch(AuthFailure('Token null'));
      } else {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('token', data.sessionToken);
        dispatch(AuthSuccess(data));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(AuthFailure(e.message));
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Probably that it returns a valid action object, i.e. object with a `type` property and whatever additional data properties. Do you have any test code examples of an attempt to test?

Comment: unfortunately, I'm not very good at this. All my attempts to test it somehow ended in failure. I need to call this action correctly and then check for data in DataReducer.

Something like that:


it('auth test', async () => {
  await AuthMethod(login , password)
  const value = store.getState().AuthData
})

Comment: I've not used redux-thunk, but typically I'd think you'd "test" your action creators via a test written against a reducer that handles the final dispatched action. Mock the fetch, pass current state and the correct parameters to the action creator to a reducer and assert the correct state output from the reducer.

Comment: Can you show me an example ? It would be cool if I had one working example (for example with AuthMethod) with which I could continue to do tests for other actions

Answer (score 0):

Simply put a `debugger` keyword on which line you pause the execution and open your developer tools and trigger your action if your action is been dispatching it will pause the execution on the line where you put the keyword `debugger`

like below I have placed a debugger in my reducer.

[image]

Comment: I need to check the operation of a specific action. then check for new data [AuthData] in dataState

Comment: When execution is paused you can check the value of every variable by stepping up, When you step up it will go to the next line and show the value at that time in the state or variable have.

Comment: I guess I don't understand something. I will ask this question in another way. How do I just execute my AuthMethod (redux action) in jest ?

Comment: Do you know about `mapdispatchtoProps` method of react-redux?

Answer (score 0):

Since redux reducers are expected to be pure functions I tend to unit test them in isolation. Like so:

```
expect(reducerFn(preConditionState, action)).toEqual(expectedStateAfterAction);
```

To test a thunk/action creator, you can mock the store and fetch, see [the docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#async-action-creators).

Then you can test your async action with fake data and verify the mocked store received the expected actions with the expected values.

Together these two approaches should cover testing your individual actions and your async/thunk actions.

Comment: I tried to do something like that. But I get an error:

expect(AuthMethod(login, password)).toEqual(AuthSuccesData);

Comment: fetchMock.getOnce('link', {
      body: JSON.stringify({
        login: login,
        password: password,
        deviceSerialNumber: '1111111',
        currentAppVersion: AppVersion,
        currentDateTime: time,
      }),
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });

    const AuthSuccesData = [
      {type: FETCH_AUTH_LOADING},
      {
        type: FETCH_AUTH_SUCCESS,
        payload: data, 
      },
    ];

    expect(AuthMethod(login, password)).toEqual(AuthSuccesData);